# Prove that d/dx (sin x) = cos x, using Taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion

Show by differentiation of the series for sin x that

$$\frac{d}{dx} (\sin x) = \cos x$$ (Using Taylor series.)

If you can given an indication or solved answer to my question would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Do you know the Taylor series for $\sin x$? Differentiate each term and then compare to the series for $\cos x$..

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right) = \dfrac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$